# Symfony Custom Form Field Type Block not rendering

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Trying to build out a custom form field type in Symfony, but the widget block is not rendering.  I set up a widget for a text field type in the same file, and that rendered properly.  What would cause my widget to not find it's template block?

MediaGalleryType.php

```
class MediaGalleryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

mediagallery.html.twig

```
{% block mediagallery_widget %}
    HTML Goes here
{% endblock %}
{% block text_widget %}
    This replaces all text type fields
{% endblock %}
```

twig.yaml

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'mediagallery.html.twig'
```

Comment: If you're not using autoconfigure, make sure to tag your service with form.type.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging around in sourcecode for Symfony form types, I found a method I can extend that returns the block prefix.

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'mediagallery';
}
```